# Angularjs UI bootstrap Datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angularjs datepicker in my application. I want to display selected date in UI. It should display "Selected Date:dd/MM/yyyy" which is working correctly. But If I select today's date it should display "Today:dd/MM/yyyy".
But for today's date also it is showing "Selected Date:dd/MM/yyy". Can anyone please help me .
my html code.

```
<div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
Selected date is: {{dt | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
<div >
    <div >
          <div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
            datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" 
            is-open="status.opened" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="false" show-button-bar="false"
            max-date="maxDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions" 
            date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" 
            close-text="Close"  ng-click="open($event)">
              <img src="calendar.png" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS code

```
 var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
 app.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.today = function() {
 $scope.dt = new Date();
 };
 $scope.today();
$scope.refresh = function(){
$scope.dt = new Date();
};

$scope.maxDate  = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()));
$scope.minDate  = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-7));

$scope.open = function($event) {
$event.preventDefault();
$event.stopPropagation();
$scope.status.opened = true;

};

$scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
$scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
};

$scope.dateOptions = {
formatYear: 'yy',
startingDay: 1
};



$scope.status = {
 opened: false
};

});
```

Comment: So the datepicker is correct, you just want to change the `Selected date is` text, to  say `Today`?

Comment: Yes datepicker is working,when I select today's date it should show "Today:dd/MM/yyyy" and for other selected date it should show "Selected Date:dd/MM/yyyy".